# How can I identify the records inside each cluster in a KNN model in SciKit-Learn Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, label, knn

I am making a KNN model. The target variable is divided in 2 categories, and the features are 3 categorical variables (country, language and company). The model says the optimal is 5 clusters, so I did it with 5.

I need to know how can I see the records in each of the 5 clusters (I mean, the countries, languages and companies that the model is grouping in each of them). Is there a way to add the labels of the clusters to the dataframe?

I tried:
predictions = knn.predict(features)

But that is only returning the estimations for the 2 labels of the target variable

I did some research and found:
km.labels_

But that only applies for KMeans, and I am using KNN

I hope somebody can tell me the equivalent for that or how to solve the problem for KNN Model please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KNN is not clustering, but **classification**.

The parameter `k` is not the `k` of k-means; it is the number of neighbors not the number of clusters...

Hence, setting k to 5 dors not suddenly produce 5 labels. Your training data has 2 labels, hence you get 2 labels.

KNN = k-nearest neighbors classification. For k=5 this means 5 nearest neighbors.

K-means clustering = approximate the data with k center vectors. An entirely different `k`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is always possible to match it back.

```
predictions = knn.predict(features)

y_test['preds'] = predictions

df_out = pd.merge(df,y_test[['preds']],how = 'left',left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

If your dataframe is called df, this should work.